# Textual Mining on the column Cell of Table that remove the Duplicates based on "##" notation

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008, oop

Let's Assume I have Table in SQL server that represents employee information for example

[image]

I want to do the Textual Mining on the Degree column that remove the Duplicates based on "##" notation.

[image]

> LINQ to SQL

I am using Linq to SQL , so I am planning to get this data in C# variable  context.And Perform operation on  string and store again to the location!

Rules: i need to update the  data or generate new table!

Is this right way of doing whether its possible ? need some suggestion on this approach or any alternative suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you need to break up the string based on the "##" delimiters, take the distinct items, and put them back in -- comma-delimited this time? The [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method to break up the string and then LINQ's [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method should get you just the unique ones.

Assuming you've got the text of the degree in a variable somewhere:

```
var uniques = degree
    .Split(new String[] { "##" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Distinct();
```

String.Split usually works with a single character delimiter, but there's an overload that allows splitting on a larger string, so you'll have to use that one.

Then you can use String.Join to comma-delimit the unique items, or whatever else you need to do.

Edit: Apologies, I thought your original question was more about how to eliminate the duplicates than how to use LINQ to SQL.

Assuming you've got your DataContext and object model set up, you just need to select your object(s) out of the database using LINQ to SQL, make the changes you need to them, and then and then call `SubmitChanges()` on them.

For example:

```
var degrees = from d in context.GetTable<Employee>() select d;
foreach (var d in degrees)
{
    d.Degree = String.Join(",", d.Degree
        .Split(new String[] { "##" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
        .Distinct());
}
context.SubmitChanges();
```

If you're new to LINQ to SQL, it may be worthwhile to run through a tutorial or two first. [Here's part 1 of a pretty good series](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43025/A-LINQ-Tutorial-Mapping-Tables-to-Objects):

Lastly, you mentioned in your edit that you have the option of creating a new table after making your changes -- if that's the case, I'd consider storing the individual degrees in a table that links back to the employee record, rather than storing them as comma-separated values. It depends on your needs, of course, but SQL is designed to work in tables and sets, so the less string parsing/processing you can do the better.

Good luck!

Comment: @Ranju Added some additional info about LINQ to SQL in the answer, hope that helps. It seems like you might be diving into LINQ to SQL for the first time, is that correct? I think it would be worthwhile to run through a full tutorial or two -- here's part 1 of a pretty good series to get you started:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43025/A-LINQ-Tutorial-Mapping-Tables-to-Objects